# How to set the userprofile using session in spring without using spring security

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

I just want to know how to set the userprofile using session in spring without spring security. and updated the example program here.

The below controller class has helpful to login the screen and it will be redirecting to the result/success page.
Here i tried to get the story field from database,It succesfully printing on the console but it is not appears on the success screen

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("person")
public class LoginController{

    @Autowired
    public PersonDAO personDAO;     

    public void setPersonDAO(PersonDAOImpl personDAO) {
        this.personDAO = personDAO;
    }
```

**New Login page:**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.GET)  
        public ModelAndView welcome(HttpServletRequest request)
        {
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");
            Person person = new Person();
            model.addObject("PersonAttribute", person);

        return model ;
        }
```

Retrieve the data using PersonDAOimpl's method select to retrieve the data from the database

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/loggedin",method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request,@ModelAttribute("PersonAttribute") Person person,HttpSession session)
        {


            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("success");
            modelAndView.addObject("person",person);
            person=personDAO.select(person);
            System.out.println(person.getStory());
             session=request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("person",person);
            modelAndView.setViewName("success");


            return modelAndView;
        }
```

PersonDAOIMPL  class has the select method to check the username and password and it will provide the data.

```
    public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO{

        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }
         public Person select(Person p)
        {
            Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
            Query query=session.createQuery("from Person where username =:username and password = :password");
            query.setString("username", p.getUsername());
            query.setString("password", p.getPassword());

            p =(Person)query.uniqueResult();
            System.out.println(p.getStory());
            System.out.println(p.getPassword());
            //p= (Per)queryResult;
            //session.getTransaction().commit();
            return p;
        }



    @Entity
    @Table(name="user_employee")
    public class Person {

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        @Id
        @Column(name="id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;
        @Column(name="username")
        private String username;
        @Column(name="password")
        private String password;
        @Column(name="story")
        private String Story;


        public String getStory() {
            return Story;
        }
        public void setStory(String story) {
            Story = story;
        }
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

    }
```

Login jsp page:username and password is the input for the below page

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form id="loginForm" method="post" action="loggedin.html" modelAttribute="PersonAttribute">

<form:label path="username">userName</form:label>
<form:input name="username" path="username" /><br>
<form:label path="password">password</form:label>
<form:password path="" name="password"/>
<input type="submit" value="login"/>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Success jsp page:redirecting the output

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>Welcome ${person.username}</center>
    <form:input name="username"value="${person.password}" /><br>
    <input type="text" value="${person.username}" disabled="true"/>
    <center>Your password is  ${person.password}</center>
    <input type="text" value="${person.password}" />
    <input type="text" value="${person.story}" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite unclear! But I found something strange in your code that maybe cause some kind of problem with displaying the user in your jsp:

You have

```
@RequestMapping(value="/loggedin",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request,
             @ModelAttribute("PersonAttribute") Person person,
             HttpSession session) {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("success");
    modelAndView.addObject("person", person);
    person=personDAO.select(person);
    System.out.println(person.getStory());
     session=request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("person",person);
    modelAndView.setViewName("success");

    return modelAndView;
}
```

The strange thing is, that you add the `person` object to the model before you load them from the DAO! So your model has the person object from the request but not the one loaded from the database.

My way to implement the controller would look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/loggedin",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request,
             @ModelAttribute("PersonAttribute") Person person,
             HttpSession session) {

    Person loadedPerson=personDAO.select(person);

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("success");
    modelAndView.addObject("person", loadedPerson);
    //System.out.println(person.getStory());       
    request.getSession(true).setAttribute("person", loadedPerson);

    return modelAndView;
}
```

---

*BTW: I would also refactor you DAO method, to make clear that the two `p` variables are different.*

Comment: thanks ralph,Its working ,I'm learning myself and i can't get any proper tutorials to understand the session concept and spring concept  as i have to build the application based on spring and hibernate and to host before december 10th